# Wrong layout on android, how to switch

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Been searching all over stack exchange and can’t find answer.

Here is code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

    Log.d("checkpoint", "1");
    //if there is a previous successful login, autofill username
    Log.d("checkpoint", "2");
    SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE); 
    Log.d("checkpoint", "3");
    final String restoredUsername = prefs.getString("adminusername","");
    if(!restoredUsername.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
      {
          Log.d("checkpoint", "5");
          final EditText adminUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.adminusername);
          Log.d("checkpoint", "6");
          Log.d("username", restoredUsername);
          adminUsername.setText(restoredUsername);    
          Log.d("checkpoint", "7");
      }


}
```

Here is the log

```
07-12 19:23:44.959: W/EGL_emulation(4171): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-12 19:23:46.150: D/checkpoint(4171): 1
07-12 19:23:46.150: D/checkpoint(4171): 2
07-12 19:23:46.160: D/checkpoint(4171): 3
07-12 19:23:46.170: D/checkpoint(4171): 5
07-12 19:23:46.170: D/checkpoint(4171): 6
07-12 19:23:46.170: D/username(4171): alexatwater
07-12 19:23:46.170: D/AndroidRuntime(4171): Shutting down VM
07-12 19:23:46.170: W/dalvikvm(4171): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0d2ab20)
07-12 19:23:46.210: E/AndroidRuntime(4171): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-12 19:23:46.210: E/AndroidRuntime(4171): Process: com.alexatwater.elhsapcalc, PID: 4171
07-12 19:23:46.210: E/AndroidRuntime(4171): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.alexatwater.elhsapcalc/com.alexatwater.elhsapcalc.AdminActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-12 19:23:46.210: E/AndroidRuntime(4171):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
07-12 19:23:46.210: E/AndroidRuntime(4171):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
07-12 19:23:46.210: E/AndroidRuntime(4171):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-12 19:23:46.210: E/AndroidRuntime(4171):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
07-12 19:23:46.210: E/AndroidRuntime(4171):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-12 19:23:46.210: E/AndroidRuntime(4171):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-12 19:23:46.210: E/AndroidRuntime(4171):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-12 19:23:46.210: E/AndroidRuntime(4171):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-12 19:23:46.210: E/AndroidRuntime(4171):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-12 19:23:46.210: E/AndroidRuntime(4171):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-12 19:23:46.210: E/AndroidRuntime(4171):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-12 19:23:46.210: E/AndroidRuntime(4171):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-12 19:23:46.210: E/AndroidRuntime(4171): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-12 19:23:46.210: E/AndroidRuntime(4171):     at com.alexatwater.elhsapcalc.AdminActivity.onCreate(AdminActivity.java:50)
07-12 19:23:46.210: E/AndroidRuntime(4171):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
07-12 19:23:46.210: E/AndroidRuntime(4171):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-12 19:23:46.210: E/AndroidRuntime(4171):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
07-12 19:23:46.210: E/AndroidRuntime(4171):     ... 11 more
```

From other posts I saw that if there is a nullpointerexpection being thrown, it is probably wrong layout. And it is. it’s set to R.layout.activity_admin but it really is R.layout.fragment_admin

When i change it in onCreate however to the right one, I also get a crash with this log

```
07-12 19:17:08.734: E/FragmentManager(4115): No view found for id 0x7f090000 (com.alexatwater.elhsapcalc:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{b10a3d78 #0 id=0x7f090000}
07-12 19:17:08.734: E/FragmentManager(4115): Activity state:
07-12 19:17:08.744: E/FragmentManager(4115):   Local Activity b1038af0 State:
07-12 19:17:08.744: E/FragmentManager(4115):     mResumed=false mStopped=false mFinished=false
```

Comment: line 50 AdminActivity.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question gets asked every day.  The dead giveaway is the auto-generated PlaceholderFragment code by Eclipse/ADT followed by user written code that tried to access elements from the layout.

The resource, `R.id.adminusername`, is in the Fragment layout file, not the Activity layout file.  Hence `findViewById` returns null when called from `MainActivity.onCreate`.

Move your code to the PlaceholderFragment's override of `onCreateView`  or `onStart`

Comment: Okay, that makes sense to move it there. But when I do, i get two warnings under checkpoint 2 and checkpoint 5 in the code:

Description Resource Path Location Type
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getPreferences(int) from the type Activity AdminActivity.java /ELHSAPCalc/src/com/alexatwater/elhsapcalc line 168 Java Problem

Comment: ^that got rid of errors, but I still am getting the same error with the code moved